# [cocosCreator, cocos2d-x]Can’t use the bind for loadScene callback function?

Tags: typescript, cocos2d-js, cocoscreator

If you use bind on the loadScene() callback function, getScene() information is not correct.

After switching from Entry Scene to Lobby Scene, I'm going to do post-processing.

It was implemented by using typeScript.

```
Entry.ts
cc.director.loadScene('Lobby', this.postProcessLobby.bind(this)(isRelogin));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDmcs.png)

The value of cc.director.getScene() in the console window indicates 'Entry'
'Lobby' is correct because it is called after switching the scene.

Another example is using the Arrow function to get the results I want.

```
Entry.ts
cc.director.loadScene('Lobby', e => this.postProcessLobby(isRelogin));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDmcs.png)

The value in cc.director.getScene() indicates 'Lobby', and the value of the lobby variable appears normal.

I prefer the bind() for async callback processing and was writing well without problems.
However, loadScene() did not get the desired result. What the hell is it? Did Scene call back without switching? Or is there another problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your first code snippet calls `this.postProcessLobby.bind(this)` with the argument `isRelogin` and passes the return value as the second argument to `loadScene`.  That probably isn't what you meant.  You could use `this.postProcessLobby.bind(this, isRelogin)` to generate a callback that will have `isRelogin` prepended to the list of arguments it is called with, which should work in your case because it looks like your `postProcessLobby` implementation ignores extra arguments, but the arrow function seems like the clear solution to me.

Comment: Looking back at the code I wrote, it looks like he tried to call after binding.
loadScene was not completed because callback was called, not registered as I intended.

thank you very much.